# Google Sceneform Tools in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, plugins, sceneform

I am a student and currently learning how to develop an apps using android studio. I need to make an AR apps and most of the tutorial I found is using plugin google sceneform tools(beta) but it is incompatible with my android studio 4.1.1 -  and I found out that Google has deprecated the Sceneform library. Therefore, it is still possible to create an AR apps without the plugin, if yes, can you tell me how?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible to create AR apps with scene form. however, the scene from repo is archived by google.

The alternative (better alternative) is [open source version of sceneform](https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk) this also includes usage examples.

Here is an application that i made with sceneform that might help [Scene Form measurement app](https://github.com/Kashif-E/ArCoreMeasurement)